# Is it ear mites or just dirty ears?

Tags: cats, health, diseases

My kitten sometimes has blackish-brown wax in her ears that I clean out with a ball of cotton. I've read cats get coffee-grounds-looking ear wax when they have ear mites but she doesn't show any sign of discomfort? No excessive ear scratching, no redness, nothing. Are her ears just naturally a bit waxy? I'd love to take her to a vet of course, but thought I'd just ask.

What is earwax in healthy cats supposed to look like?

Answer (score 2):

Please do not put any object into your cats ears as it will often do more harm than good.

Earwax is a mix of dust-dead skin-dead bacteria-virus and an oily substance this combination is often black or very dark.

if mites are present you will see it if you smear some earwax on a white paper,it will have a dark red color(it is best if you leave this to your vet).

Your cat will take care of her earwax on her own so you should not need to do anything.

Earmites will cause discomfort and your cat will scratch the ears a lot,your vet will look for ear mites at your cat`s regular check up.